# Проверка на наличие файла gulp

Tags: gulp

Всем доброго времени суток!
Встал такая проблема, в сборке используется 2 шаблона и в каком-то шаблоне файла есть, а в другом его нету. Проблема в том, что когда файла нету, то gulp крашится и пишет `Error: File not found with singular glob:`
Может нужно добавить проверку на наличие файла? Тоже пробовал, не получилось(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается, тем что нужно нужно установить параметр {allowEmpty: true}

```
return src([
  'sources/'+theme+'-theme/scripts/**/*.js',
  'sources/'+theme+'-theme/uikit/bootstrap/utils.js'
], {allowEmpty: true})
```